# What does [param: NotNull] mean in C#?

Tags: c#

In Entity Framework's source code ([link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Relational/Storage/RelationalConnection.cs#L74)) I found this line:

```
public virtual IRelationalTransaction Transaction 
{ get; [param: NotNull] protected set; }
```

The `[param: NotNull]` part looks very strange to me. Any idea what kind of a C# syntax is this? I'm familiar with attributes and param but not this combination.

The definition of NotNull is this:

```
[AttributeUsage(
    AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Parameter |
    AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Delegate |
    AttributeTargets.Field)]
internal sealed class NotNullAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Which I expected to be used simply as `[NotNull]` but what is `param` doing here?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

When you mark method with `NotNull` it means, that method returns not null object:

```
[NotNull]
public object Get()
{
    return null; //error
}
```

When you mark setter it does the same - setter returns not null (because .net converts properties to get and set methods).

```
public virtual IRelationalTransaction Transaction { get; [NotNull] protected set; }
```

Equals to:

```
[NotNull] 
public virtual void set_Transaction(IRelationalTransaction value) { ... }
```

So, you need to add `param:` to point, that "i mean - parameter of setter is not null, not a result of set-method":

```
public virtual IRelationalTransaction Transaction { get; [param: NotNull] protected set; }
```

Equals to:

```
public virtual void set_Transaction([NotNull] IRelationalTransaction value) { ... }
```

Comment: the setter does not return value. what do you mean by "setter returns no null" in you answer

Comment: @HakamFostok stroingly, it returns `Void`, and you can mark any method with `NotNull`, even if it returns "nothing" (void).

Comment: Isn't the generated setter method `protected`?

Comment: @chi maybe, i don't remember exactly, but I rink, it's not important for this question

Answer (score 41):

`param:` is the attribute target. See: [Attribute specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-specification)

The attribute target can be one of these:

> assembly, module, field, event, method, param, property, return, type

So `[param: NotNull]` means that the `NotNullAttribute` applies to the `value` parameter of the setter. It is necessary to specify the target here, since the `value` parameter does not appear as a method parameter explicitly.

---

A common use of the attribute-target  is to specify the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8) in order to make types and members declared as `internal` visible to unit test projects.

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTestProject")]
```

The assembly does not appear as a language construct, therefore the attribute-target `assembly` is the only way to specify an attribute for the assembly. Btw: It can be specified in any source code file.

Comment: I think this was supposed to be the accepted answer, but anyway.

Comment: Is there a version of that link for something more recent than .NET 1.1?

Comment: Unfortunately the [C# Language Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) is only avaialable as download, so I cannot give you a direct link.

Comment: UPDATE: Now the language specification and reference is available here: [C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/)