# Using [NotNull] for a method's parameters

Tags: c#

Consider [this code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L57) from ASP.NET MVC's source code:

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseMvc(
            [NotNull] this IApplicationBuilder app,
            [NotNull] Action<IRouteBuilder> configureRoutes) {...}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32528271/1646540) answer, the annotated parameters must not be null. Then why can I pass null to the method?  That is, in the case below, why doesn't the compiler give me any error?

```
app.UseMvc(null);
```

Comment: Related: [NotNull attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30896853/464709).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The only attribute that can cause the compiler to generate an error is the [`ObsoleteAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). It is because this attribute's behavior is hard-coded into the compiler.

Attributes like the `NotNull` attribute are generally meant for tools (like ReSharper) to generate warnings or errors while writing code. Please read about this particular attribute [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#NotNullAttribute).

You can also use tools like PostSharp to [issue additional build-time errors](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Validating-parameters-field-and-properties-in-PostSharp-3).

Comment: link https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Engineering-guidelines#argument-null-checking doesn't talk about [NotNull]

Comment: But analyzers can generate warnings and if you set TreatWarningsAsError it'll surely break your build.

Comment: This is actually wrong, NotNull on a method parameter means that after the method is called the parameter is not null, not that null cannot be passed into that parameter.

Answer (score 16):

If you wish to move Null checks to be implemented by aspects and not need to be done by hand. The clear solution is to use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) the open source build weaver. Specifically you want to leverage the [NullGuard Fody](https://github.com/Fody/NullGuard)

> PM> Install-Package NullGuard.Fody

Should be everything required to get set up to use Fody with null guards. The documentation shows how you can have fine grain control if you desire.

---

**2019 Update**

C# 8 and .NET Core 3.0 permanently eliminate null reference exceptions.

[Tutorial: Migrate existing code with nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/upgrade-to-nullable-references)

[Tutorial: Express your design intent more clearly with nullable and non-nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types)

Comment: Why should that eliminate all null reference exceptions? Any public or protected method you still have to check. The caller might not use C# or not C# >= 8.0, have nullable reference types disabled or simply ignore the compiler warning.

Comment: Yes and developers can still make mistakes with the new attributes or the null-forgiving operator `!`.

Answer (score 0):

The NotNull Attribute on a method parameter indicates that after the method runs the parameter is not null.

The compiler will generate a warning if the method can exit without ensuring the parameter is not null

```
void AssertNotNull([NotNull] string param)
{
    if(param is null)
    {
         throw new NullReferenceException();
    }
}

string? name = GetName();
AssertNotNull(name);
// the next line will not cause a warning because the compiler knows
// the AssertNotNull method ensures name cannot be null here
var length = name.Length;
```

Comment: I suspect this answer refers to the [NotNullAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute) of the C# 8 nullable reference type feature, while the original question, given its date, refers to some [legacy attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30898593).